# How to change the start screen based on a condition in Power Apps?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I searched a long time online, and I tried a lot of things but it's going nowhere (Lookup, IsBlank, Len, First, Switch, Navigate, OnStart, StartScreen, DataCard...).

First I have one list (List1) in Sharepoint. In this list I have multiple columns. What I want from my PowerApp is to open the Screen1 if the cell in ColumnX (date type) of the selected item is blank (no data), and Screen2 if there is a record (for ex: 10/17/2023).

Whatever I do, when I double click on an item to modify it, it doesn't work. It always opens the same screen, no matter the selected item.

You can see some of the things I tried :

If(IsBlank(DataCardValueCell),Screen1,Screen2) - in App.StartScreen, returns false either their is something or not
If(IsBlank(List1.ColumnX),Screen1,Screen2) - in App.StartScreen, same
If(LookUp(List1.ColumnX,'ColumnX'=Blank(), true), Screen1,Screen2)

I also tried to Refresh() and to do the same in App.OnStart .
Refresh the website page before selecting another item doesn't change anything either.

I think it's because it checks the whole Table but I can't manage to have only the cell I want.

Thanks for your help in advance, I really appreciate !

Comment: Are you creating a standalone canvas app or customizing the SharePoint list forms using Power Apps?

Comment: I am customizing the SP list form using Power Apps

Answer (score 0):

If you are customizing the SharePoint Online list form using Power Apps,

You can get the column values from `SharePointIntegration` object as well.

Try setting `App.StartScreen` property to:

```
If(
    IsBlankOrError(SharePointIntegration.Selected.ColumnX),
    Screen1,
    Screen2
)
```

and see if it works for you.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for getting back to me. Yes I am using a sharepoint list online and customizing it from Power App, I tried your idea, but it always show the first screen too no matter what :/